# Scraping table from Wikipedia with Python

Tags: python, numpy, beautifulsoup, html-table, wikipedia-api

I am trying to scrape Wikipedia Table using Python & Beautiful Soup. When I try to get the table columns attributes with a for loop I get the error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-948408e65d8d> in <module>
      1 # Header attributes of the table
      2 header=[th.text.rstrip() 
----> 3         for th in rows[0].find_all('th')]
      4 print(header)
      5 print('------------')

NameError: name 'rows' is not defined
```

How can I fix this?

#### The code:

url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_municipalities_of_Norway"

> Initiating multiple URL requests. If the request is successful, then expected HTTP response status code is 200.

```
s=requests.Session()
response=s.get(url, timeout=10)
response

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
```

> Title of wikipedia page

```
soup.title.string
```

> Get the right table to scrape

```
right_table=soup.find('table',{"class":'sortable wikitable'})
```

> Header attributes of the table

```
header=[th.text.rstrip() 
        for th in rows[0].find_all('th')]
print(header)
print('------------')
print(len(header))
```

Comment: Where does the rows come from?

Comment: From the right_table=soup.find('table',{"class":'sortable wikitable'}). This finds the table with the HTML tag "sortable wikitable" from the Wikipedia webpage. Should I set a rows=[] before calling it in the find_all function?

Comment: Yes. Only when you initialize a list can you append values to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `pandas`which will be very straight forward in your case:

```
import pandas as pd
tables  = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_municipalities_of_Norway")
right_table = tables[1]
```

**Output**

```
|     |   Number[1](ISO 3166-2:NO) | Name                         | Adm. center          | County               |   Population(2017)[2] |   Area(km²)[3] |   CountyMap |   Arms | Language form[4]         | Mayor[5]                    | Party   |
|----:|---------------------------:|:-----------------------------|:---------------------|:---------------------|----------------------:|---------------:|------------:|-------:|:-------------------------|:----------------------------|:--------|
|   0 |                        301 | Oslo                         | Oslo                 | Oslo                 |                673469 |         454.03 |         nan |    nan | Neutral                  | Marianne Borgen             | SV      |
|   1 |                       1101 | Eigersund                    | Egersund             | Rogaland             |                 14898 |         431.66 |         nan |    nan | Bokmål                   | Leif Erik Egaas             | H       |
|   2 |                       1103 | Stavanger                    | Stavanger            | Rogaland             |                141186 |         262.52 |         nan |    nan | Bokmål                   | Kari Nessa Nordtun          | Ap      |
|   3 |                       1106 | Haugesund                    | Haugesund            | Rogaland             |
```